# How to render d3.layout.tree so that it spreads downwards (root at the top)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I found a fantastic tree as below which meets almost my needs. 
However, I would like to expand lengthwise the tree. Could anyone give 
me any ideas how to make it or any reference sites. Any help will be 
appreciated.

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "expanding lengthwise the tree". Could you please clarify?

Comment: @user635090 Sorry, my description is poor. I would like to move "ROOT" node to top of display not left.

Comment: It means I want to a downward direction.

Comment: In other words, I want to rotate the tree by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, rotating is simple mathematical process.

If the original coordinates of the point are `{x,y}`:

```
{-y,x} = rotated 90° (anti-clockwise)
{y,-x} = rotated -90° (clockwise)
{-x,y} = mirrored along y-axis
{x,-y} = mirroded along x-axis
{-x,-y} = mirroded along both
```

These switches should be done in all path- and coordinate-calculations. Quite a job, I think.

Is it possible to include the whole pattern into single `DIV`? Then you could try to rotate this `DIV` with CSS3-transform.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to do it soon.

Answer (score 3):

The example tree you are looking at has actually been rotated from the default so that it is left to right. That's why in all the 'translate' statements, the x and y coordinates are swapped from where they would normally be.

To return this example to top to bottom orientation, do these two things:

1) For nodes: Swap the x and y coordinates in each of the translate statements:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
```

should be changed to

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")"; })
```

and the same for all other "translate"s.

2) For links: Remove the '.projection' method from

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

So that it just says

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();
```