# Inverting co-ordinates in SVG image

Tags: javascript, svg

I am making an image from a set of co-ordinates using svg. I load the JSON object inside my java-script and then create the required elements ( svg frame, polygons, lines etc etc ) as I need.

```
 //x1,x2,y1,y2 are all passed here as method arguments
 var vLine = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg:line")
 vLine.setAttributeNS( null, "x1", new String( x1  ) + "px" );
 vLine.setAttributeNS( null, "y1", new String( y1  ) + "px" );
 vLine.setAttributeNS( null, "x2", new String( x2  ) + "px" );
 vLine.setAttributeNS( null, "y2", new String( y2  ) + "px" );
 vLine.setAttributeNS( null, "style", "stroke-width:1;stroke:black");
```

The image is showing up fine but the problem is that it is shown inverted along the y-axis. I did some reading and came to know that the initial co-ordinate system begins from the top-left of the page instead of the bottom-right and that if I inverse the scale, it would get fine. So I added another attribute to my lines as

```
 vLine.setAttributeNS( null, "transform" , "scale(-1)")
```

But it seems that my image is not showing in the svg frame anymore. My best guess is that if I have to altered the scaling factor, then I would also have to change something in the co-ordinates as well on the x and y axis as well to make sure that the image fits back in the frame but I am unable to figure out the factor by which to control the co-ordinates.

```
//A sample of my co-ordinates json
[9.632932,47.347601],[9.594226,47.525058],[9.896068,47.580197], ....
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [A table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9053315/1169519) of basic co-ordinate convertions.

Comment: I tried the conversions (to mirror it along y-axis). Calculation took longer than usual ( about a couple of seconds ) and after-wards the image didn't come up at all.

Comment: You should consider to create the correct coordinates into your original data, rather than make long-polling conversions with JS. What comes to the hidden elements, they are now _above_  the Y axis (which is at the top of `svg`), you need to move them to the correct position by adding a suitable value to each Y coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much re-search and trial/error attempts, I came up with the solution and I'll share it here for any other who might be searching for the same thing. The original problem was that I had a series of co-ordinates (of countries) that I needed to map on my page inside an SVG element. The issue was that these co-ordinates were real world co-ordinates and they needed to be inverted ( mirrored ) so that they could be shown upright on the HTML co-ordinate system ( as I described in the question ). I used the following algorithm to convert them.

```
//Here x and y are my co-ordinates
function transform(x,y){
        if(x === 0 && y === 0 ) {
            y = 90;
        }
        var tranformedX = (totalWidth/360)*(x+180);
        var tranformedY = (totalWidth/360)*(-(y/Math.cos(Math.PI*(y/360))))+275;
        return {x: tranformedX, y: tranformedY};
}
```